# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' (When running eas build -p android)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-build

ERROR ON EXPO BUILD:

```
[stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

[stderr] 
> Multiple task action failures occurred:

[stderr] 
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable

[stderr] 
      > Android resource compilation failed

[stderr] 
        ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/assets_phone.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

[stderr] 
            

[stderr] 
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable

[stderr] 
      > Android resource compilation failed

[stderr] 
        ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/assets_fire.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

AND

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

Tried npx expo prebuild, but still facing same issues. Appreciate if anyone could help :(